# Playing one sprite sheet after another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Heyo, i have this sprite sheet http://codepen.io/benasl/pen/yabpxo that i want to be changed to another one after it ends, and after the second one ends the first one needs to start again, and so on... I don't know that much of jquery to accomplish this kind of result. What would be the best way to do this?

```css
body {
    background-color: #69e4c3;
}
.kambarys {
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/pra08AS.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 380px;
    height: 372px;
    top: 100px;
    left: 40%;
    animation: convejor 3s steps(76) infinite; 
   
}

@keyframes convejor {
 from { background-position:    0px; }
 to { background-position: -28880px; }
}
```

```html
<div class="kambarys kambarys-1"></div>
```

Comment: Is the second one placed in a different div?

Comment: Would it help if the second one was places in a different div?

Comment: Depending what you want, will you have control over this div element by using javascript or do you prefer to use pure css?

Comment: javascript would be more interesting i think. But can you atchieve such result using only css?

Comment: http://codepen.io/benasl/pen/yabpxo I made it to change with a delay, however it blinks when it changes, maybe some one know how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Is quite complicated to implement this feature with pure CSS, since you want to create a loop of two animations.
Instead, I would suggest using `Javascript` + `CSS`.
So you can actually combine them and have more control over your animations

Take a look of this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/9140/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 setInterval(function(){
   $('.kambarys').toggleClass('second');
  },3000);
});
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #69e4c3;
}
.kambarys {
    background-image: url('https://i.imgsafe.org/a37470f198.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 380px;
    height: 372px;
    top: 100px;
    left: 40%;
    animation: convejor 3s steps(76) infinite; 
}

.kambarys.second {
   background-image:  url('http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/monster.png');
   animation: convejor2 3s steps(10) infinite;
   width: 190px;
}

@keyframes convejor {
 from { background-position: 0px;}
 to { background-position: -28880px;}
}

@keyframes convejor2 {
 from { background-position: 0px;}
 to {background-position: -1900px;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="kambarys"></div>
```